# Recover from unresponsive state, when Watir::Browser hits a URL with an infinite loop running

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, watir

I have a requirement where I have to test websites that might have an infinite loop, hence if an infinite loop website is encountered, then my app should skip and test the next website in the list.

P.S. I wrote my own test URLs in html and JS (with an infinite loop) to test this.

However when Watir::Browser URL hits the infinite loop url, I get a Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout exception that I catch and then try to move to the next URL with a browser.goto. But thenceforth every attempt results in the same exception. Even a browser.exist? or a browser.close gives the same exception. Unable to do any operation on the browser object.

Any clues as to how I can recover my browser so that I can make Watir::browser go to the next URL?

Thanks!

Comment: Please update the program so that we can understand clearly.

Comment: What is the meaning of infinite loop website?

Comment: Do you meant to say infinite loop is something which loads forever?

Answer (score 0):

A `Net::ReadTimeout` means that the driver went off to do what you told it, and the Ruby code decided it wasn't coming back. Even if you rescue the exception, you can't give the driver another instruction, because it's still working on the request that you know can never be fulfilled.

Watir/Selenium is not the right tool to test if a website will have an infinite loop. I would recommend using an HTTP Library to ensure that a page will load before trying to access it with Watir.

Alternately, you can create & close a different session (Watir will kill the process for you on `browser.close`) for each call to a potentially looping site.

Comment: `because it's still working on the request that you know can never be fulfilled`. I don't think so, if that's the case then we can't even stop execution and start our next execution because driver wouldn't be available to us.

Comment: @Rajagopalan , yes by an infinite loop website I mean a site that takes forever to load and never completes loading. I have encountered a few websites in the past.

Comment: @titusfortner , maybe you are right, the driver went off to do what I told it, and because of this, I cannot even execute a browser.close from Ruby code.

Comment: @GregF Try it out in chrome, chrome browser will be closed once your execution over even though it meet up with the error you said, driver closing the browser is the last step driver would do before it dismantle the instance, so it doesn't go on to do the Job you asked to do, he is wrong.

Comment: @GregF you can execute `browser.close` in an after hook of your test runner, or if you've rescued the ReadTimeout exception.

Comment: @Rajagopalan the process is killed in the OS if the driver doesn't respond to the quit command. The browser doesn't matter at all. The bottom line is that the exception can be rescued, but the driver can't continue to be used.

Comment: @titusfortner, you are right: 'the exception can be rescued, but the driver can't continue to be used.'. That's exactly what I am seeing in my app.

Comment: @titusfortner okay, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider something like:

```
require 'watir'

some_array_of_urls.each do |url|
  begin
    browser.goto url
    # ...
  rescue Net::ReadTimeout
    log_error
    @browser = nil
    next
  end
end

def browser
  @browser ||= Watir::Browser.new
  @browser
end
```